# How to set the cursor position?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to know how I can edit directly in the console application. I mean, when I open the application I will see "Edit the code : GW1020" and I want to set the cursor after zero and when the user presses backspace to delete zero to remain "Edit the code : GW102", how could I do that ? I tried overwriting but it doesn't work because I get zero at the end,
this is the code as I tried to write it:

```
private void EditCode(string code)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("> Edit code: " + code);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("> Enter the Name: " + products[code].Name);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("> Enter the Quantity: " + products[code].Quantity);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("> Enter the UM: " + products[code].UM);
    Console.WriteLine();
    
    ConsoleKeyInfo info;
    do
    {
        info = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && code.Length > 0)
        {
            code = code.Remove(code.Length - 1);
            Console.CursorVisible = true;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("> Edit code: " + code);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 0);
        }
        else if (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            code += info.KeyChar;
            Console.Write(info.KeyChar);
        }
    } while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```